# Deadlift and scapular retraction

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, bodyweight-exercises, deadlifts, weights

most of the people say it's wrong to do the scapular retraction (by squeezing blades) during deadlifts. [This](https://nattyornot.com/should-i-retract-my-shoulders-during-deadlifts/) and [this](https://stronglifts.com/deadlift/) are two references which explain that scapular retraction is not advised because:

- it increases ROM
- it makes you feel the weight harder and this may cause injuries

Ok, I may understand that. But, I've always been told by my personal trainers that the scapular retraction is very important in most exercises (bench press, squat, lateral machine, row etc) because it fixes the shoulders and so prevents them from injuries. So,

- why shouldn't we apply this to deadlift too?
- how can be the upper back protected during deadlift?

Comment: If you try to squeeze your shoulder blades together while deadlifting 400+ pounds, you’ll tear your rhomboids.